# simulator for a cartesian(gantry) robot

Tags: gazebo, moveit, robot, cartesian

I wanna simulate a cartesian(gantry) robot in a simulator and solve the forward and reverse kinematics.  Is it possible with Gazebo or MOVEIT? which one and how? Or if you suggest any free software
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, obviously a cartesian robot can be simulated in Gazebo.

Typically, a cartesian gantry robot has translational motion axes that are parallel to the cartesian reference frame axes, so both the forward as well as  the inverse kinematics is trivial.

So if you want more specific answers, you will need to ask more specific questions.

Comment: thank you. is there any  tutorial for gazebo to simulate a gantry robot? I have a gantry robot that has an end effector with 3 DOF. I want its forward and reverse kinematic and dynamic. I think in move it we have just kinamtic not dynamic.?

Comment: You mean gantry 3DOF translation + end effector with 3 DOF orientation? For kinematic and dynamic model I would have a look at [KDL](https://github.com/orocos/orocos_kinematics_dynamics). For Gazebo have a look at the [official demo](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/building_robot). You will have a combination of prismatic and revolute joints. Wrt. MoveIt I don't know.

Comment: yes 3 dof orientation. thank you.